# How Can I Enable Custom PHP Error Logging in IIS?

Tags: php, iis, error-logging

I am running Windows Server 2016 and IIS version 10 and I would like to save a separate *daily* PHP error log.  Currently, by default, the log is written to C:\Windows\temp\PHP71x64_errors.log, but I would like to create a new log each day.  The reason for this is because it would be helpful to me to prevent the one temp log file it creates by default from getting too large, which it has in the past, slowing down the server.

Any ideas on ways I can do this?  I've researched this and can't seem to find an answer that explains exactly how to do this.  I know how to edit the log itself and choose what is and what isn't logged, but how would I make a separate PHP error log for each day and have it save to a certain folder?

Thanks.

Comment: on other boxes i use `logrotate` ... surely there is a port for win. https://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/wiki/LogRotate/

Comment: So there is no way to do this without using a separate tool?  The function is not built-in and simply needs to be enabled?